# Teradata: Date value division with 365 days

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata, teradatasql

Needs an update what exactly the below query does when it divisible by 365??

```
select CAST((FLGHT_DATE )/365 AS INTEGER);
```

Note: FLGHT_DATE column is of date type and in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Teradata DATE data type keeps the date internally  as an integer: (YEAR - 1900) * 10000 + (MONTH * 100) + DAY. dividing this by 365 doesn't make a lot of sense but I should allow a Teradata expert to offer advice.

Comment: It will return a basically meaningless number. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Got the info, we have to use this in our partition by clause, actually in the converted code to snowflake. based on this anwser i can easily convert to snowflake format. Thank you all.

Comment: This logic wouldn't make a lot of sense for a Snowflake clustering key.  Would be good to understand how you plan on using this for Snowflake.